# py.test fixture scoped 'session' is executing once per module/file. Is there a global single run fixture scoping option available?

Tags: session, scope, pytest

Does anyone have any insight on this? I am trying to figure out the differences between 'session' and 'module' scope.

This question has been asked before in different terms, but never really answered.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your title is wrong I'm afraid - `session` scoped fixtures are exactly what you're asking for (running once per *test session*), while `module` scoped fixtures run once per module (i.e. file).

Comment: That seems not be the case. Please see the example repo and included test output for more context: https://github.com/mehmetg/pytest_session_fixture_test

Comment: That's because you're importing your fixtures in your test files. Your file should be named `conftest.py` (not `configtest`), be in the directory you're running `py.test` from, and you should not import anything from there.